# Записать еще один объект в state в React

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

У меня есть стейт с объектом. Нужно записать в него еще один.

```
this.state = {
            meal: {
                type: null,
                participants: null,
                budget: null,           
                activity: null,
                error: null,
                key: null
            },
   
}
```

Данные приходят из апи, но при нажатии на кнопку нужно, чтобы записался еще один продукт. + проверился, нет ли в стейте такого же. Тогда не записывать.

```
addItem = (meal) => {
        const newItem = {meal};
        if (newItem.key !=== this.state.meal.key) {
        this.setState(({meal}) => {
            const newMeal = {...meal, newItem};
            return {
                this.state = newMeal
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильный флоу. В стейте должен быть массив с обьектом,  так будет более правильно работать со структурой данных. Но для вашей ситуации можно применить такое решение:

```
const addItem = meal => {
  const { meal: current } = this.state;
  /**
   *  meal уже должен быть обьектом
   * */
  if (meal.key === current.key) return;
  this.setState(({ item }) => ({ ...item, ...meal }));
```

};